# Changing multiple iFrames with same class name

Tags: javascript, iframe, svelte

I've probably not done this correctly to begin with but, I have a #each loop in Svelte creating iframes and setting the src as {vid}.

I'm also then reloading them with : document.getElementById('youtubebox').contentWindow.location.reload();

Is there a way I can reload all of them with them having the same class name? Currently only the first one reloads.

```
{#each vids as vid}
  <div class="col-md service">
     <iframe class="youtubebox" width="300" height="225"
     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{vid}">
     </iframe>> 
   </div>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for this purpose like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.youtubebox').forEach(function(iframe) {
    iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
});
```